# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined in React-redux while running a test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I know there has been a lot of "cannot read property ".find" fo undefined" questions, but I have been looking at them and have not found an answer that I am looking for. 
I am running a test of my components.. and this one does not pass.. I was able to make the other tests pass.. but the ".find" returns an undefined error.. been looking at it the whole morning, but cannot find the solution.. can anybody help me?
Here is the commentList.test.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import { CommentList } from 'components/commentList';
import Root from 'Root';

let wrapped;
beforeEach(() => {
  const initialState = {
    comments: ['Comment 1', 'Comment 2']
  };

  wrapped = mount(
    <Root initialState={initialState}>
      <CommentList />
    </Root>
  );
});

it('creates one LI per comment', () => {
  expect(wrapped.find('li').length).toEqual(2);
});
```

Here is the commentList.js file

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CommentList extends Component {
  renderComments() {
    return this.props.comments.map(comment  => {
      return <li key={comment}>{comment}</li>
    })
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.renderComments()}
          </ul>
      </div>
    )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    comments: state.comments
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CommentList);
```

and finally the Root.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from 'reducers';

export default ({ children, initialState = {} }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers, initialState)}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Here is what can bee seen in my terminal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnqtA.png)

Comment: What are you using as a test framework? Jest? Jasmine? Also, I guess we have to wrap `beforeEach` and `it` inside `describe`

Comment: I am using jest..

Comment: nope it doesnt work either..

Answer (score 1):

This may have come a little bit late.. I was not able to give my answer at that time because I have not the required reputation to give an answer.. lol.. but for those who have been following this question and wondering where i did the fix.. here it is:

replace this line of code

```
import { CommentList } from 'components/commentList';
```

with this:

```
import CommentList from 'components/commentList';
```

Hope this will be helpful for someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

try looking for hostnodes:

```
it('creates one LI per comment', () => {
  expect(wrapped.hostNodes().find('li').length).toEqual(2);
});
```

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/hostNodes.md

Comment: Hey guys, I was able to resolve the issue... and for those who might want to know what the issue is for your future codes that you might run into.. here is the problem.. I made a small mistake on the import of component CommentList.test.js..
import { CommentList } from 'components/commentList'; there should have no curly braces enclosing the CommentList component.. I didn't notice it for the whole day.. because I was looking at the import above it that has the curly braces on it.. my mistake.. happy coding yo' all!